# Looking for a Solution to different web.configs in a Git Repo

Tags: git, coldfusion, web-config, coldfusion-10

So in my development instance and in my production instance there are some minor changes in my web.config file for rewriting. However there are many similarities. What is a common/good/best solution for tracking the files, but still some how keeping them correct.

My thought was to make a web.config.prod and a web.config.dev and push them that way for me. Then when I pull just remove the .dev or .prod depending on my needs. Then add it back when I commit files again.

What I am currently doing is I keep the production version in the repo and on my dev instance I just don't every commit it, but I find my self often needing to uncheck the box in TortiseGit. I don't think ignoring the file would work. That would ignore it all together right?

This is a private repo so I am not concerned with how others would use it.

If this solution can be solved with some sort of "dynamic" web.config I would be open to that as well. Here are the reasons the web.config can differ.

1. Canonical domain name to remove the www. Obviously my domain on prod and dev differ so if I use one file it sends me to whichever is in that file.
2. Often we find ourselves working on a project in a folder of the domain on development but at the root level in production. So I have to add /folder in development and just / in production.

If I could get around this with a better web.config I would be open to that. Otherwise I just need an organized solution for Git.

Thoughts on a viable solution to organize this code?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually managed with web.config transformations.  You have a build configuration for debug, and a build configuration for release. Then you have web.config files for each of these configurations describe the different values depending on the environment.  When you publish your site to a particular configuration, any relevant transforms are made to the base web.config.

See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I just started scanning that document. I am using Coldfusion for my development. Do I have to then use Visual Studio (Which I don't have) to do this transformation stuff? It looks to be so.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry,  what I was talking about is very specific to ASP.NET web development.  I saw web.config in your question and assumed that was your development environment.

Comment: I didn't specify coldfusion. I'll add the tag. Thanks for your help though.